# Wrong path results the python program runs using crontab

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cron

I have a script in python under Linux that needs to determine the current working directory. The part of program that does this is:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print cwd
```

When I run the program it gives me the right answer:

```
/home/johny/LST/CT
```

But when I run it using crontab, it gives me this:

```
/home/johny
```

Even when I put it in deeper folders, the same path results. Does anybody know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron probably just sets itself to your home directory. If you need your script to run in a particular directory consider using something like

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

at the top of your script although really your script should not care where it's run from. All your file paths in the script should be relative to the script, using something like:

```
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

mypath = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'data', 'mfile.dat')

... etc ...
```

Answer (score 5):

In your crontab file do:

```
1 0 * * * cd /home/johny/LST/CT; python your_script.py
```